# Maven Compiler Plugin Build Failure with Werror argument and present warnings marked to be skipped

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I am trying to use Maven compiler plugin to show all warnings and to fail the build if any warnings are there by configuring "Werror" parameter. My Pom.xml file settings for maven compiler plug in is -

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArgs>
        <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-deprecation</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-unchecked</arg>
        <arg>-Xlint:-rawtypes</arg>
        <arg>-g</arg>
        <arg>Werror</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In my project , I have these 3 warnings - deprecation, unchecked, rawtypes.
If I remove these  arguments, then the build fails which is perfectly fine. -

```
    <arg>-Xlint:-deprecation</arg>
    <arg>-Xlint:-unchecked</arg>
    <arg>-Xlint:-rawtypes</arg>
```

But when I add these arguments, compiler should ignore these kind of warnings and build should succeed.
But still Build is failing and doesn't show any specific error.
Build succeeds if I remove this argument.

```
 <arg>Werror</arg>
```

So I am not able to run a successful build If we skip some of the warnings which are present in the project. Is there any way to achieve the same ?

PFB the error output of the mvn build command -

```
    [INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
     [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.abcd:project:war:1.0
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: com.abcd.xyz:common:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.3 @ line 87, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building PROJECT 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ vsmvam ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ess/p4-sources/abcd/xyz/project/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.6.1.201212231917:prepare-agent (default) @ vsmvam ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/ess/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.6.1.201212231917/org.jacoco.agent-0.6.1.201212231917-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/ess/p4-sources/mgmtplatform/vshield-main/vsmvam/target/jacoco.exec,excludes=com/vmware/vshield/vsm/**
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ vsmvam ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ vsmvam ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 330 source files to /home/ess/p4-sources/abcd/xyz/project/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.590s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Oct 06 01:51:08 PDT 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/892M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project vsmvam: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project vsmvam: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:976)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Fails with this error - 







 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project vsmvam: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project vsmvam: Compilation failure
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)

Comment: Please post the full error and log output...

Comment: Added the error output of mvn build command.

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of changes I was able to finally figure out how to build successfully with "Werror" flag if all the Lint warnings are fixed.

I removed - "true"
Could not figure out exactly whats the reason why the build fails when we use Javac compiler.

Along with added UTF-8 encoding and suppressed Processing Lint warnings.

Working copy of configuration is -

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
         <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
         <arg>-Xlint:-processing</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```